# Search box with React-Query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-query

I am trying to implement Product search by `text`. Fetching data with `react-query`. The following implementation is working but it does not feel right to me. Let me know if I am overdoing it and if there is a simpler solution with `react-query`.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useQueryClient } from 'react-query';
import ProductCard from '@/components/cards/ProductCard';
import { useQueryProducts } from '@/hooks/query/product';
import { selectSearch } from '@/store/search';

// function fetchProductsByFilter(text){}

const Shop = ({ count }) => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const { text } = useSelector(selectSearch);

  const productsQuery = useQueryProducts(count);

  useEffect(() => {
    setProducts(productsQuery.data);
    setLoading(false);
  }, []);

  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  useEffect(() => {
    const delayed = setTimeout(() => {
      queryClient.prefetchQuery(['searchProductsByText'], async () => {
        if (text) {
          const data = await fetchProductsByFilter(text);
          setProducts(data);
          setLoading(false);
          return data;
        }
      });
    }, 300);
    return () => clearTimeout(delayed);
  }, [text]);

  return (
    <div className="container-fluid">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-3">search/filter menu</div>

        <div className="col-md-9">
          {loading ? (
            <h4 className="text-danger">Loading...</h4>
          ) : (
            <h4 className="text-danger">Products</h4>
          )}

          {products.length < 1 && <p>No products found</p>}

          <div className="row pb-5">
            {products.map((item) => (
              <div key={item._id} className="col-md-4 mt-3">
                <ProductCard product={item} />
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

// async function getServerSideProps(context) {}

export default Shop;
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It doesn't seem very idiomatic to me. With react-query, the key to using filters are to put them *into* the query key. Since react-query refetches every time the key changes, you'll get a refetch every time you change a filter, which is usually what you want. It's a very declarative way of doing things. No useEffect needed at all.

If this happens when choosing something from a select or clicking an apply button, that's really all you need:

```
const [filter, setFilter] = React.useState(undefined)
const { data, isLoading } = useQuery(
  ['products', filter], 
  () => fetchProducts(filter)
  { enabled: Boolean(filter) }
)
```

Here, I am additionally disabling the query as long as the filter is `undefined` - fetching will start as soon as we call `setFilter`.

---

if typing into a text field is involved, I'd recommend some debouncing to avoid firing off too many requests. The [useDebounce hook](https://usehooks.com/useDebounce/) is very good for that. You'd still have the `useState`, but you'd use the debounced value for the query:

```
const [filter, setFilter] = React.useState(undefined)
const debouncedFilter = useDebounce(filter, 500);
const { data, isLoading } = useQuery(
  ['products', debouncedFilter], 
  () => fetchProducts(debouncedFilter)
  { enabled: Boolean(debouncedFilter) }
)
```

Answer (score -4):

If this happens when choosing something from a select or clicking an apply button, that's really all you need:

```
const [filter, setFilter] = useState<string>('')
const isEnabled = Boolean(filter)
const { data, isLoading } = useQuery(
  ['products', filter], 
  () => fetchProducts(filter)
  { enabled:  enabled: filter ? isEnabled : !isEnabled, }
)

 <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setFilter(e.target.value)}/>
```